# Ankhsvn "update solution" in VS2013 also retrieves all sibling folders not associated with the VS project

Tags: visual-studio, svn, ankhsvn

I'm seeing some unexpected behavior in Ankhsvn and I'm wondering if this is possibly a bug, or by design and I'm misunderstanding something.

I'm using an online subversion repository, and have some repositories set up with this file structure:

```
"Browser URL": https://www.zzzzz.com/code/mememe/subversion-2/nodes/HEAD/trunk  
"Checkout URL": https://subversion.zzzzz.com/svn/abc.MyMiscProjects/

SqlScripts1 
SqlScripts2 
SomeOtherStuff1
SomeOtherStuff2
VS2013_Solution1
VS2013_Solution2
```

Up until now, I had been using all of these different svn repository folders with different local home folders with no problems (using TortoiseSVN).

I also have the AnkhSVN plugin installed in VisualStudio, but have been using it primarily with other SVN repositories (at the same online provider).

Yesterday from within VS2013, I created VS2013_Solution2 and when it asked if I wanted to add it to Subversion source control, I said yes.  I checked in all my files, but then when I went to my home PC and from Visual Studio did a "File, Open Subversion Project", and chose the .sln file within /VS2013_Solution2, not only did it get the selected solution, *but also every other sibling folder within that repository*, even though they have no association with the solution.

Similarly, when this morning at work I did an "Update solution to latest version" within VS2013, it also pulled all folders from that repository down as sibling folders to VS2013_Solution2 within the local folder.

Now, if this was just the default expected behavior of svn as a whole, I would expect the exact same thing to happen when I right click my local VS2013_Solution2 folder in Windows Explorer and choose TortoiseSVN "SVN Update", but in that case it only updates the individual folder.

Is there some point I am missing here about the behavior of Ankhsvn with respect to all files in an individual SVN repository?  Is it fundamentally incapable of dealing with a *subset* (individual subfolder) of a repository as TortoiseSVN seems to be able to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some more googling....
In VS2013, File, Subversion, Change Source Control, I see:

```
Repository: https://subversion.zzzzz.com/svn/abc.MyMiscProjects/    
SCC Binding:  ^/trunk/  
SCC Binding URL: https://subversion.zzzzz.com/svn/abc.MyMiscProjects/trunk
```

There is a "..." button beside "SCC Binding Path" that shows the Solution Root as:

```
"https://subversion.zzzzz.com/svn/abc.MyMiscProjects/trunk"  
...but in the dropdown I am also able to choose:  
"https://subversion.zzzzz.com/svn/abc.MyMiscProjects/trunk/VS2013_Solution2"
```

(Interestingly, none of the other folders show up.)  So in my case, choosing the path pointing directly to my project folder cleared up the undesired behavior.

So from this, I conclude that the *default* behavior for Ankhsvn is to always assume the *entire* repository.  And while this can apparently be overridden, it seems to me that it wouldn't be a good idea.

Probably the most practical approach is:  use one local root folder on your hard drive for each individual subversion repository - Do not try to micro-manage individual folders in one repository to different local folders, and if you really need to be able to check out just one individual folder, there is probably a very specific order of steps to do so (if doing it from within Visual Studio, as opposed to TortoiseSVN for example).